# KDE Plasma Ubuntui Studio 20.10 LArger Format Fonts in 2160p enviroment

Tags: display-resolution

SO I just upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10 and am new to KDE PLASMA enviroment.

Now the Zoom function is locked in at 100 percent and I need to cut that in half.  Everything is giant.  Now I reformatted icons and task bar to be as small as possible, but things are still to big.  On the log in screen for instance it is giant.  It needs to be the same format as it is for 1080p.  That's why I have dual monitor.  2160p and 1080p.  More resolution for having multiple windows open to use as work station.  If evrything is giant;  That doesn't work and is juevenile.